# why no output is displaying

Tags: c++

Why this code is not displaying any output: Instead if we use

```
cout << &s1.f
```

or

```
cout << &s1.i
```

gives the proper output.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct s
{
char c;
int i;
float f;

}s1;

int main()
{
cout << &s1.c;
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized anything.

Comment: why initialization needed? cout << &s1.i; will give correct output.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal, my bad. I misread the question and didn't realize it would be initialized to 0 in the first place. See the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an overload of `operator<<` that takes a `char*` and displays it as a null-terminated string. If you want to display the pointer address, cast the pointer to `void*`.

Comment: Ohh great!!! casting to void* giving the exact answer.  buy why cout << &s1.i without casting giving the right answer.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal, there's no special overload for `int *` like there is for `char *`. A `char *` represents a string, so they provided an overloaded operator for it. An `int *` has no special significance.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the addres of `c` makes the type a `char*`, which will be interpreted as a null terminated string. Global variables by default are zero initialised meaning `c` will be interpreted as an empty string, and thus nothing is printed.