# how to get address of particular element in a string

Tags: c++, c, string

`char a[]="helloworld";`

I want to get address of 'l'?

`(a+2)` or `&a[2]` gives *lloworld*. And adding other ampersand shows error.

Then how to get address of 'l'?

If not possible, please explain?

Comment: I assume you're outputting it: use `static_cast<void *>(&a[2])` for an address output. If so, its a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817278/why-no-output-is-displaying/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, but if you want to output it you'll have to either:

- for C: use an appropriate format string (for C):
  `printf("address: %p\n", &a[2]);`
- for C++: avoid string interpretion by cout by casting to a `void*`:
  `cout << "address: " << static_cast<void*>(&a[2]) << endl;`

Comment: -1 the correct print-formatspecifier for an address in C is %p not your %x

Comment: @vjshah Why did you tag it as C then?

Comment: @user411313, didn't know about %p. Now I do. Good call.

Answer (score 7):

`a + 2` is the address of the third element in the array, which is the address of the first `l`.

In this expression, `a`, which is of type `char[11]`, is implicitly converted to a pointer to its initial element, yielding a pointer of type `char*`, to which `2` is added, giving the address of the third element of the array.

`&a[2]` gives the same result.  `a[2]` is equivalent to `*(a + 2)`, so the full expression is equivalent to `&*(a + 2)`.  The `&` and `*` cancel each other out, leaving `a + 2`, which is the same as above.

How this address is interpreted in your program is another matter.  You can use it as "a pointer to a single `char` object," in which case it's just a pointer to the first `l`.  However, you can also interpret it as "a pointer to the C string contained in the array starting at the pointed-to `char`, in which case you get `"lloworld"`.  It depends on how you use the pointer once you get it.

Comment: in C,we can get da address by printf("%d",&a[2]) and 'lloworld' by printf("%s",&a[2])..But since in C++,we have cout only which by default takes string(wat compiler shows)..so how to get address then

Comment: @Vj, what makes you think you have only `cout` in C++? You have `printf` right there in the cstdio header. And that code isn't *getting* the address. That code is *printing* the address. You already *get* the address with the code you and everyone has shown: `a + 2` or `&a[2]`. Your problem is in printing that value so it looks like an address.

Comment: @RobKennedy ya agree wid that... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/):

```
char *lAddress = strchr(a, 'l');
```

This will point to the start of `l`.
You can print this using `printf` using the `%p` descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

[`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) will return a pointer to (*address of*) the first occurrence of a given character in a string.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it gives up 'lloworld'. If you use it as a C-string it will still be null terminated. Just start a bit further on in the sentence.

Comment: in C++,cout<<&a[2] outputs whole string after 2 elements by default..In C,its nt a prblm...So,to get address of particular element in a string in C++,it cant be done by &a[2]...then wats da way?

Comment: You have the address - a `char *`. `cout` uses this as a string. Do you want the raw address - then cast it to `void *`.